# SymPy solve(): UnboundLocalError: local variable 'solved_syms' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using SymPy to solve a equation, code as followed.

I have made a simpler example but this problem may relate to the original equations, so I will choose to post the original code here instead of the simplified one.

```py
from sympy import *

dP, rho, nu, D, miu, L, Q, Re, eps, f = symbols('dP, rho, nu, D, miu, L, Q, Re, eps, f')

solve([Eq(Re, rho * nu * D / mu),
       Eq(L / D, 0.05 * Re),
       Eq(L / D, 1.359 * Re ** (1/4)),
       Eq(dP, 32 * miu * L * nu / D ** 2),
       Eq(dP, 128 * miu * L * Q / pi / D ** 2),
       Eq(dP, f * (L/D) * (rho * nu ** 2 / 2)),
       Eq(f, 64 / Re),
       Eq(1 / sqrt(f), -1.8 * log ((eps / D / 3.7) ** 1.11 + 6.9 / Re))],
      [Re, D, f])
```

With error message:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-884b0835e135> in <module>
      7        Eq(f, 64 / Re),
      8        Eq(1 / sqrt(f), -1.8 * log ((eps / D / 3.7) ** 1.11 + 6.9 / Re))],
----> 9       [Re, D, f])

G:\Program-Files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py in solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
   1094         solution = _solve(f[0], *symbols, **flags)
   1095     else:
-> 1096         solution = _solve_system(f, symbols, **flags)
   1097 
   1098     #

G:\Program-Files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py in _solve_system(exprs, symbols, **flags)
   1834             return rv
   1835 
-> 1836         solved_syms = set(solved_syms)  # set of symbols we have solved for
   1837         legal = set(symbols)  # what we are interested in
   1838         # sort so equation with the fewest potential symbols is first

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'solved_syms' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you input the wrong equations. Try:

```
solve([Eq(Re, rho * nu * D / mu),
       Eq(dP, f * (L/D) * (rho * nu ** 2 / 2)),
       Eq(1 / sqrt(f), -1.8 * log ((eps / D / 3.7) ** 1.11 + 6.9 / Re))],
      [Re, D, f])
```

and the error will be gone. You input the right equations.

But you will find that SymPy seems not able to solve this.

```py
NotImplementedError: could not solve 9*sqrt(f)*log(58510807926309*2**(11/100)*(dP*eps/(L*f*nu**2*rho))**(111/100)/125000000000000 + 69*dP*mu/(5*L*f*nu**3*rho**2)) + 5
```

Even after proper transformation, we can see that `Re` and `f` are constant-relevant with `D`, however, `D` satifies:

```py
solve(Eq(e**(1 / (u * D ** x)), d/(D**y) + u/D),
      D)
```

[image]

where everything besides `D` are constant.

It also can't be solved by SymPy:

```py
NotImplementedError: multiple generators [D, D**y, e**(D**(-x)/u)]
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation e**(D**(-x)/u) - D**(-y)*d - u/D
```

A closed form solution probably not exists. This equation will need to be solved numerically. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774718/how-to-solve-this-ln-fracax-fracbxc-frac1u-xv-where?noredirect=1#comment7769877_3774718

So you can use `nsolve` of `sympy`, meaning `numerical solver`. Or `fsolve` of `scipy` is OK too.

```py
from sympy import *

L = 4.11 * 10 ** 5
nu = 1
rho = 0.8175
mu = 2.88 * 10 ** -6
dP = 20000
eps = 4.6 * 10 ** -5

Re, D, f = symbols('Re, D, f')

nsolve((Eq(Re, rho * nu * D / mu),
       Eq(dP, f * L / D * rho * nu ** 2 / 2),
       Eq(1 / sqrt(f), -1.8 * log ( (eps / D / 3.) ** 1.11 + 6.9 / Re))),
      (Re, D, f), (1123, -1231, -1000))
```

where `(1123, -1231, -1000)` is the initial vector to find the root. And it gives out:

[image]

The imaginary part are very small, both at 10^(-20), so we can consider them zero, which means the roots are all real. Re ~ 13602.938, D ~ 0.047922 and f~0.0057.